# Making shapes that are not supported in three js

Tags: three.js

Beginning Three js I have made some shapes and done a few things with animations, but I wanted to make a shape that was in the three js geometries, namely a biconcave shape. I tried experimenting with the sphere geometry and the knot geometry to see if I could come up with something, it was close but not quite there, I was wondering whether it would be better to just make the geometry from scratch myself, it may require me bumping up my maths to do it.

Comment: I'm really not sure how to answer this question, if it is not supported by threejs, you're almost by definition forced to create a geometry yourself, no? :)

Comment: @BrendanAnnable yes I guess so...